# Check if character column contains numeric value in DB/2 with sql

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

We have an AS400 that the db/2 is stored on and I am trying to join a table where character column contains the value of a numeric column.

I am running this in visual studio and I tried cast(val as char) and receive a 'as' not recognized, I tried `CONVERT`, and that isn't recognized either. Here is my original query:

```
SELECT        *
FROM           tab e, tab n
WHERE        (e.LN = 0001) AND (n.RMK LIKE '%' + e.ORDNO)
```

n.RMK contains a character value which is consistent but something like, "ordr 1401" and then e.ORDNO contains a numeric value which would be 1401

I want to see if e.RMK contains the 1401 value in e.ORDNO.

When I run that query I get a Errot type 6 = Numeric data that is not valid error. So I figure I would try and convert the numeric value to char and try again.

Like so,

```
SELECT        *
FROM           tab e, tab n
WHERE        (e.LN = 0001) AND  n.RMK  LIKE '%' + cast(e.ORDNO as  varchar(10))
```

This did not work,

I also tried

`n.RMK LIKE '%' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), e.ORDNO)`   and I get CONVERT not recognized.

Comment: Afaik `+` is not a string operator, try `||` instead. DB2 is not MS SQL Server, there's no `CONVERT`, too :-)

Comment: Instead of CAST(val AS CHAR) try using CHAR(val). And of course see @dnoeth 's comment.

Comment: Thank you both. I was able to finally get it to work using CONCAT and CHAR as suggested. I posted the answer. If any of you see anything wrong with it please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got a working solution although it may not be the best:

```
 SELECT        *
 FROM           tab e, tab n
 WHERE        (e.LN = 0001) AND  (n.RMK LIKE CONCAT(RTRIM(CONCAT('%', CHAR(e.ORDNO))), '%'))
```

There was whitespace being added to the end of the e.ORDNO string for some reason using CHAR and there was whitespace at the end of the RMK string too; and the wildcard search wouldn't work unless I prepended and appended the '%' to e.ORDNO or I did a right trim on both n.RMK and e.ordno. Not sure if one way is better than the other.

Comment: You could use `||` instead of `CONCAT`, it makes for better readability imo: `n.RMK LIKE (RTRIM('%' || CHAR(e.ORDNO)) || '%')`

Comment: Readability is a matter of opinion. And since the '|' character is not an invariant character, CONCAT should be preferred.

Comment: You don't have to use `CONCAT` as a function, it can be used as an operator like this `'%' concat rtrim(e.ordno) concat '%'`.

Answer (score 0):

First off, best practice is to use explicit joins.

Secondly, `CAST (fld AS CHAR)` should work, though it defaults to CHAR(1).  You probably need more than that.

Third, assuming the prefix is always "ordr " I'd use a SUBSTR()

```
SELECT *
FROM tab e 
     JOIN tab n ON n.rmk = INT(SUBSTR(e.ordno,6))
WHERE e.ln = 1
```

Comment: CAST will not work for me because VS keeps throwing an error saying "AS" is not recognized.